# How to manage v-bind and v-on together, with Vue2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my line of code  inside a v-foor loop :

```
<div class="box-comment" v-for="p in products">
   <span v-on:click="addProduct(@{{ p.sku_f }})" class="btn text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</span>
</div>
```

I know I can't use moustaches inside attributes. I should use v-bind but in this case I already have a v-on.....

how should apply both?

Comment: Just pass parameter as you would in javascript: `addProduct(p.sku_f)`

Comment: you mean... v-on:click="addProduct(p.sku_f )"   ?

Comment: lol... so simple... thx

Answer (score 1):

If you have used any vue directive, it will automatically interpolate it as vue variable. SO you just need to do following:

```
<div class="box-comment" v-for="p in products">
   <span v-on:click="addProduct(p.sku_f)" class="btn text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</span>
</div>
```